# Formatting 2D array with older version of NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, formatting, vectorization, partial-application

I have a code snippet to format a 2D array to a specific string format. The code snippet works well with recent versions of NumPy (e.g. 1.9.2), but the same fails with NumPy 1.4.1, which is the current version for CentOS 6.6.

```
import numpy as np
cfmt = '%14.6E'
vfmt = np.vectorize(cfmt.__mod__)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1762, in __init__
    nin, ndefault = _get_nargs(pyfunc)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1694, in _get_nargs
    raise ValueError, 'failed to determine the number of arguments for %s' % (obj)
ValueError: failed to determine the number of arguments for <method-wrapper '__mod__' of str object at 0xb461e0>
```

From [Numpy-discussion](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2010-September/052655.html), this appears to be an issue with `functools.partial`, with a recommend workaround to use `lambda`. However, here are my failed attempts:

```
vfmt1 = np.vectorize(lambda x: cfmt.__mod__(x))
vfmt2 = np.vectorize(lambda x: cfmt % (x,), ['|S14'])  # attempt to specify otype

# A 2D array with shape (1, 3)
ar = np.array([[1.0e35, 9.999999, 10.0]])

print(vfmt1(ar))  # [['  1.0000' '  9.9999' '  1.0000']]
print(vfmt2(ar))  # [['  1.0000' '  9.9999' '  1.0000']]
```

These values appear to be strings clipped to 8 characters, and are essentially garbage.

The expected formatted result using a recent version of NumPy is:

```
array([['  1.000000E+35', '  9.999999E+00', '  1.000000E+01']], type='|S14')
```

Any suggestions on how to get the expected outputs using older versions of NumPy? Or generally how to vectorize formatting of numeric arrays to character arrays?

Comment: FYI: You are running into a bug that has been fixed in newer versions of numpy: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2485

Comment: Thanks, however I require a solution for an older version of NumPy, since that is the supported version available to me.

Comment: Does `vfmt = np.vectorize('{:14.6E}'.format)` work?

Comment: Any `vectorize`d function that returns a string will result in a dtype of `S8`,  giving you truncated strings.

Comment: @askewchan from Python 2.6.6 that style of formatting throws "ValueError: zero length field name in format"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input array is one-dimensional, a simple list comprehension will work:

```
>>> ar
array([  1.00000000e+35,   9.99999900e+00,   1.00000000e+01])
>>> ar2 = np.array(["%14.6E" % v for v in ar])
>>> ar2
array(['  1.000000E+35', '  9.999999E+00', '  1.000000E+01'], 
      dtype='|S14')
```

For a 2-d array, a nested list comprehension will work.  For example, here's a 2-d array `x`:

```
>>> x
array([[  1.00000000e+35,   9.99999900e+00,   1.00000000e+01],
       [  1.23450000e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   1.23000000e+02]])
```

Here's the nested list comprehension that creates a list of list of strings:

```
>>> [["%14.6E" % v for v in row] for row in x]
[['  1.000000E+35', '  9.999999E+00', '  1.000000E+01'], ['  1.234500E-04', '  0.000000E+00', '  1.230000E+02']]
```

If you need the result to be a numpy array, just put that in a call to `np.array`:

```
>>> np.array([["%14.6E" % v for v in row] for row in x])
array([['  1.000000E+35', '  9.999999E+00', '  1.000000E+01'],
       ['  1.234500E-04', '  0.000000E+00', '  1.230000E+02']], 
      dtype='|S14')
```